# How to get a format of the given date or time in php?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

How to get a format of the given date or time in php?

If I give date like this,

```
2022-03-08 06:45:06
```

It should return `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`

Is there any possible way to get the format from date?

Comment: No, you cannot get the format of the date. The reason: PHP cannot know what is the day or the month for the first 12 days. "03" kan be either month or day.

Answer (score -1):

i dont think there is such a function.

if you need to handle dates in different formats, reformat them in timestamp and then in the needed format

you can try something like this

```
  $timestamp = strtotime("2022-03-08 06:45:06");
  $newFormat = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp)
```

Comment: They didn't ask how to format the date, they want to know the format of a date string. Completely different. In the question, they already have it in this format so why would they need to reformat it?